What does ばかり mean in this sentence?
Came across this sentence when reading a bit and was wondering how ばかり changes the meaning of the sentence.

なんで俺の家にヤバい奴ばかり集めるんですか

Which i guess is something like:

Why are you gathering/sending these bad guys to my house?

I've read that ばかり has alot of meanings and grammar rules but i dont seem to get this one.
First post. Sorry in advance if i did something wrong.

Maybe the literal meaning is "only", as in "Why are you gathering only bad guys to my house?" But in this sentence, I think ばかり is acting to emphasize the complaint in a more general way: "Why are you gathering so many bad guys to my house?" or "Why are you always gathering bad guys to my house?"
Look at these two examples from「プログレッシブ和英中辞典」(link), and how they translate them:

朝から晩まで文句ばかり言う
He does nothing but complain from morning till night.


人の本ばかりを借りる
He is always borrowing other people's books.


Ah, that makes sense. Yeah, the "only" meaning felt a little off from context so the emphasis feels like the correct one. Thank you! Thanks for the links!
